# ModelChoiceField in django admin gives 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.' error

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-admin, django-errors, modelchoicefield

Hej!

I want a field in my django admin area where the user can select from given choices in the database.
For example get a list of countries and choose one. But I will always get the ' Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.' error  when you try to save the new instance.

```
#models.py

class PlaceSection(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=1)

        def code_str(self):
        return self.code
```

```
# admin.py

class InstiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    place_sections = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        PlaceSection.objects.values(),
        widget=Select2Widget,
    )
    

    class Meta:
        model = Something
        fields = [
            "place_section"]


class InstiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = InstiForm
    save_on_top = True
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    fieldsets = [
        (
            ("General"),
                {"fields": [
                    "place_sections"
                    ]
                }
            )
        ]
```

I do get the right choices in the admin dropdown but when I select one and save the error occurs.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this (in the admin) found only similar problems without the admin part and no solution worked for me.

Help is really appreciated! :)

Edit:

I fixed the issue in my admin-area but now can't filter for PlaceSection in my forms/views.
The needed fields are there, but after the 'search' the TypeError 'PlaceSection' object is not iterable occurs. It seems to be a NoneType and empty but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any further help is appreciated as well! :)

```
# forms.py

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    place_sections = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=PlaceSection.objects.all(), widget=Select2MultipleWidget, required=False)
```

```
# views.py

def search_institution(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = filter_query(form)
            context = {"result_data": serialize(query), "form": form, "show_form": False}
            return render(request, "stakeholders/search_form.html", context)
    else:
        form = SearchForm()

    context = {
        "result_data": serialize(Institution.objects.all()),
        "form": form, 
        "show_form": True
    }
    return render(request, "stakeholders/search_form.html", context)
```

```
# query.py

def filter_query(form):
    query = Institution.objects.all()
    if form.cleaned_data["place_sections"]:
        place_sections_query = Institution.objects.none()
        for section in form.cleaned_data["place_sections"]:
            place_sections_query = (
                    place_sections_query
                    | Institution.objects.filter(place_sections__in=section)
            )
        query = query.intersection(place_sections_query)
    return query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelChoiceField` accepts a `queryset` argument. Your code is missing that.

```
place_sections = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        PlaceSection.objects.values(),
        widget=Select2Widget,
    )
```

should be as follows:

```
place_sections = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=PlaceSection.objects.all(),
        widget=Select2Widget,
    )
```

And probably not `values()` but `.all()`

Check out the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It does work this way. I tried values() to get the names and not the ID in the dropdown, still working on that :D

Comment: I also created a ModelAdmin `@admin.register(NaceSection)
class PlaceSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = [
        "place_sections",
    ]` and it does give me a field where I can choose between the choices, but I can't search in it. End it still doesn't give me the country, but the ID. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, in Django the value for select box is by default PK of the model. To change it you should use to_field_name attribute. Just make sure the values are always unique, which is in your case. Take a look at this section in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name

Comment: I fixed that aswell, but now can't filter via my forms. 
The TypeError 'PlaceSection' object is not iterable occurs. Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you are using PlaceSection in a for loop. Can't say anything precise without seeing the template (or wherever this loop is) but one thing to consider is. Please search for that error on internet.

Comment: found the for loop. Thanks alot for the ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

@moddayjob helped me a lot!

Complete solution for my problem is:

```
# models.py 

class PlaceSection(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    def code_str(self):
        return self.code

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.code}, {self.description_german}"

class Institution(models.Model):
   place_sections = models.ManyToManyField(
        PlaceSection,
    ) 

   def serialize(self):
       return {"place_sections": ", ".join([place.code for place in self.place_sections.all()])}
```

```
# admin.py

@admin.register(NaceSection)
class PlaceSectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = [
        "code",
        "place_sections",
    ]


class InstitutionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        model = Institution 
        fields = [
            "place_sections"
        ]


@admin.register(Institution)
class InstitutionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = InstitutionForm
    save_on_top = True

    fieldsets = ["place_sections"]
    autocomplete_fields = ["place_sections"]
```

```
# query.py
def filter_query(form):
    query = Institution.objects.all()
        if form.cleaned_data["place_sections"]:
        place_sections_query = (
            Institution.objects.filter(place_sections__in=form.cleaned_data["place_sections"])
            )
        query = query.intersection(place_sections_query)
```

```
# forms.py

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    place_sections = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=PlaceSection.objects.all(), widget=Select2MultipleWidget, required=False)
```